# flask not responding with template

Tags: python-3.x, flask, python-3.6

I am running a flask server in testing but the `render_template()` method is not responding

Here is my **app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request
from feeders import feeder

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def feed():
    if request.method == "GET":
        data = feeder.all_feed()
        return render_template("feed.html", allfeed=data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

I am using `ThreadPoolExecutor` for some of my tasks, here is how the ***all_feed()*** method looks like.

```
def all_feed():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=7) as executor:
        results = list(executor.map(get_feed, feeder_site_urls.values()))

    print(results)

    return results
```

I can see **results** on the terminal but the template is not rendering.
And yes all my templates are under *templates/*.
Edit: I can see that the flask is consuming memory (gradually increasing)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was a bug in one of my templates
Always remember to run in `DEBUG` Mode.
Also create a ***.flaskenv*** file with following contents

```
FLASK_APP=app.py
FLASK_ENV=development
FLASK_RUN_PORT=8000
FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
```

Thanks to one of my friend